# how do I align bootstrap tabs in the center?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tabs like these:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="#tab_default_1" data-toggle="tab">
            Tab 1
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#tab_default_2" data-toggle="tab">
            Tab 2
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#tab_default_3" data-toggle="tab">
            Tab 3
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But instead of having them on the left, I'd like them in the center. I tried `text-align:center;` and even setting `margin-left:0` and `margin-right:0` but neither is working. What's the easiest way to do this without re-writing the whole code?

Here's a jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/j751b1mb/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
.nav-tabs > li {
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
}

.nav-tabs {
    text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j751b1mb/4/

Comment: What the `*` is doing - `*display` .. I am n00b, so asking,. :)

Answer (score 47):

In Bootstrap 4:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center">
```

Comment: Most simple, and best solution thanks!

Answer (score 27):

You have added a lot of custom CSS, but the easiest Bootstrap way is to use `nav-tabs` and `nav-justified`..

http://www.codeply.com/go/upP3lh2gxS

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
     <li>..</li>
     ..
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j751b1mb/5/

The key is to set display: flex on the nav tabs and align them in the center of the page.

```
.nav-tabs {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

You can get more fine-grained control over the specific position of the tabs by modifying the margins on `.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li`

```
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs > li {
   margin: auto 2px;
}
```

The code above will distribute them evenly across the line, for example.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this and replace with this

```
    .nav-tabs > li
    {
    float: none;
     text-align: center;
    }
    .nav > li 
    {
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change in  css

```
.tabbable-line{
 text-align:center;
}
/* Default mode */
.tabbable-line > .nav-tabs {  
  display:inline-block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r9d82vjy/)

Answer (score -1):

Use text-center or text-middle class on your main element.